# In how many years will the account value be equal to $2P$ dollars?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $P$ dollars is invested in a savings account that pays $5$ percent annual interest, compounded continuously, in how many years will the account value be equal to 2P dollars?

My answer:
$$A= Pe^{rt}$$

So, $2P=Pe^{0.05t}$

Divide by $P$ and $P = e^{0.05t}$

Take natural log of $P$: $\ln P = \ln e^{0.05t}$.

Then, $\ln P=0.05t\ln e$

Divide by $0.05$:  $\frac{\ln P}{0.05}=\frac{0.05t}{0.05}$.

$$t = \frac{\ln P}{0.05}$$

Now, if the above is correct, how do I find the actual amount of years?

thank you

Comment: Welcome to math SE! Here's a mathjax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $2p/p=2$, not $p$.

Comment: thanks for the correction Paul. So, changing this, then I would have something like  2= e^(0.05*t) . Taking natural log of 2, I would get ln2= 0.05*t and the answer would be t= 13.86. Would it be correct to say it would take almost 14 years?

Comment: The solution to this problem leads to the “rule of 70” for estimating the time to double an investment.

Answer (score 2):

Dividing $2P=Pe^{0.05t}$ by $P$ we have $2 = e^{0.05t}$ (it is $2P$ not $P^2$), so:

$$t = \frac{\ln 2}{0.05}$$

Comment: Well, thanks, I need a numeric value or if it's too large then a number (2) and its exponent.

Comment: It is $13.862943....$

Comment: The process looks correct from my perspective. However, the online math problem I am using has multiple choice answers and I don't see the answer listed there. The answer choices are: 2^30 years, 2^5 years, 10 years and 20 years.